# Initializer list reference type safety

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error, pass-by-reference

Below is some test code I expect to print "Hello world" twice. In fact, it prints "Hello world" once and then throws an `Access Exception`.
The code to print both of the messages are near-identical:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace::std;

class VectorWrap1 {
public:
    vector<string>& v;

    // *** Reference parameter ***
    VectorWrap1(vector<string>& v_) : v(v_) {} 
};

class VectorWrap2 {
public:
    vector<string>& v;

    // *** Non-reference parameter ***
    VectorWrap2(vector<string> v_) : v(v_) {} 
};

int main(){
    vector<string> v = { "Hello world" };

    VectorWrap1 w1(v);

    // ***** Prints "Hello world" *********
    cout << w1.v[0].c_str() << endl;

    VectorWrap2 w2(v);

    // ***** Throws access exception *****
    cout << w2.v[0].c_str() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems as if VectorWrap2's reference member is being initialized by the constructor's non-reference parameter without any conversion taking place.

Shouldn't this generate a compile-time error?

Comment: With proper compiler options, you'll get a warning for the ctor of `VectorWrap2`.

Comment: @dyp: Strangely, not with VC++.

Comment: I am in fact using Visual studio

Comment: @ChristianHackl Even with all warnings enabled?

Comment: @dyp: Exactly. With `/W4`, it just spits out pretty useless warnings about not being able to generate the assignment operators (because of the reference member). With `/Wall`, it generates about 1000 warnings, but all of them are nonsense stuff about its own standard library implementation. Nothing about the temporary in the constructor.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Have you disabled language extensions? There's an infamous extension that deals with binding temporaries of class type to references.. maybe with language extensions, vc++ is doing something weird here, or ignores it.

Comment: @dyp: Yes, I use `/Za` by default. Here is the complete call (VC 2013): `cl /nologo /EHsc /W4 /Za stackoverflow.cpp`.

Comment: @dyp: btw, the language extension you are referring to still generates a warning with `/W4` when it is actually used (at least in my experience), but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VectorWrap2`'s constructor is setting `v` to be a reference to a temporary `vector` created when the constructor is called. That string is destroyed after the call and w2.v[0] then references something that no longer exists. As @dyp pointed out, this should definitely generate a warning.

That said, what sort of "conversion" were you expecting to take place? I'm not sure I understand that part of your question.

Comment: To me, it seems as if the OP already knows this. There is an actual question at the end of the OP that your answer... doesn't answer.

Comment: He said he expected it to print "Hello World" twice, so I took this to indicate that he didn't understand that the temporary had disappeared.

Comment: Ah, yes. I focused on the text below the code sample. Still, I think it'd be interesting to know if there's a rationale why this isn't considered an error.

Comment: By 'conversion' I meant the 'conversion' done by an assignment operator used to initalize a reference-type, from a value to an address. Conversion probably is the wrong word.... That part of the question was just my (incorrect) guess at what the problem could be.

Comment: In C++, references are just pointers with some syntactic sugar - they simply copy the address of the object used to initialize them. They're very light-weight for this reason, but binding one to a temporary is Not A Good Thing (TM).

Comment: @sfjac: I strongly disagree with the idea of references being syntactic sugar. References might be implemented in terms of pointers by the compiler, but on the language level enable features impossible to realise with pointers. You won't be able to write a generic swap function with pointers, for example.

Comment: @Christian I'm curious about that: If `x` and `y` are pointers to some template type then isn't `auto temp = *move(x); *x = move(*y); *y = move(tmp);` a generic swap using pointers?

Comment: @AndyMcoy: Well, you can easily write a function that takes two `T*` objects, yes, but it's only truly generic if you don't have to pass a pointer at all, i.e. if `int i = 1; int j = 2; swap(i, j);` is possible.